# VB.NET: Null reference with an Interface

Tags: vb.net

I have a null reference warning. Dummy code as follows:

```
 Dim poo As IEnumPooTypes
 Toilet.GetPooInBowl(poo)
```

The variable 'Poo' says it may result in an object reference not set error but I cannot use the 'New' keyword with an instance. How do I make the warning go away?

Comment: Whatever you do, can you do `.flush()` afterwards? :p

Comment: You have to be 13 years old to get a user account here.

Answer (score 2):

You can't instantiate an interface if `IEnumPooTypes` is an interface. The `I` is implying that it is an interface. You need a concrete implementation of `IEnumPooTypes`.

Answer (score 0):

VB.NET only gives you `ByVal` (which is an in parameter) and `ByRef` (which is an inout parameter). But I think you want to use poo as an out parameter. In this case you need to annotate the declaration with `<System.Runtime.InteropServices.Out( )> ByRef` (you can if course import `System.Runtime.InteropServices` and write `<Out()> ByRef`).