# How to avoid Warning when accessing an Interface ByRef

Tags: vb.net

i want to access a element in a dictionary of interfaces:

```
Public Interface IWorker
    Sub doSomething()
End Interface

Private Sub Test()

    Dim MyDict As New Dictionary(Of Integer, IWorker)()
    Dim Worker As IWorker

    If MyDict.TryGetValue(0, Worker) Then
        Worker.doSomething()
    End If

End Sub
```

It works but i get a Warning: "Variable 'Worker' is used before it has been assigned a value"

I found this Question: [VB.NET: Null reference with an Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385050/vb-net-null-reference-with-an-interface) but for the solution i had to change the "TryGetValue" Function.

What is the best way to get rid of the warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to get rid of this is to assign it a value, the value doesn't have to be an actual object, it can just be `nothing`

This should work:

`Dim Worker As IWorker = Nothing`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Perfect! I was stuck in "it is not possible to instantiate a interface" that this simple solution did not come to my mind. My next "Workaround" would have been creating a dummy object which implements my Interface... Thank you!